# Mail-server how-to

Tags: 15.04, mail-server

What I need is a basic mail server, I'm going to send e-mail from internal systems to it and then fetch the e-mail externally(gmail).

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 server and mail-server component that comes with the installation. What more do I need? Which conf files do I need to look at? I can't find any guide or how-to on the mail-server component.

TIA
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com) is a great mail server and easy to setup. You can have an eye on it. It's great .

But if you really want to do things natively you should look at the [official domcumentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer)

Comment: Zimbra is great

Comment: yeah I used it myself. Wonderful